# How can I disable the "Apply Gift Card" entry during checkout?

Tags: magento2

I am making a store that never intends to offer gift cards.

I'm stumped how to disable the "**Apply Gift Card**" form on the payment step of checkout.

There isn't a clear way to do this via the admin. Disabling just the block won't also disable the JavaScript that is pulled in - and that causes other problems.

This is for **Magento 2 Enterprise Edition**. Disabling *just* the **Magento_GiftCard** module seems potentially problematic because of the dependencies it is involved with.

Comment: The only option you have is to disable that module from using command or from your config.php file there is no option to disable it from admin settings, i had same issue and endded up same result. Did contact with magento support regarding its settings they also replied same, by the way i was using magento 2.2.0 EE Cloud.

Comment: That's the problem. Properly disabling the Magento_GiftCard module via command-line ("bin/magento module:disable Magento_GiftCard") is problematic because Magento_Enterprise,           
Magento_GiftCardImportExport, 
Magento_AdvancedCheckout,     
Magento_MultipleWishlist,     
Magento_PricePermissions and  
Magento_GiftCardStaging all depend on it. How one does that gracefully isn't clear to me.

Comment: Confirmed the dependencies listed in the above comment are still there in Magento 2.3.3.  Wild.  A simple "Enable/Disable" is what Magento needs on this.

Comment: Why not only hide it using CSS?

Answer (score 10):

To remove this from the checkout, create a file in your theme called **checkout_index_index.xml**

*i.e. For the checkout page: Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml*

Add the following to it...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="giftCardAccount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="componentDisabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

#christmastree

Don't forget to clear the cache.

The checkout is using [Magento's UI components](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/ui_comp_guide/bk-ui_comps.html), see Magento's devdocs for more info on how to [customise the checkout](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/howdoi/checkout/checkout_overview.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is the best way to completly solve this probleme :

**Create a new Module then,Remove component from Checkout Page:**

VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml

```
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="checkout.root">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="jsLayout" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="components" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="checkout" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="steps" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                        <item name="billing-step" xsi:type="array">
                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                <item name="payment" xsi:type="array">
                                                    <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                        <item name="afterMethods" xsi:type="array">
                                                            <item name="children" xsi:type="array">
                                                                <item name="giftCardAccount" xsi:type="array">
                                                                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                                                                        <item name="componentDisabled"
                                                                              xsi:type="boolean">true
                                                                        </item>
                                                                    </item>
                                                                </item>
                                                            </item>
                                                        </item>
                                                    </item>
                                                </item>
                                            </item>
                                        </item>
                                    </item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </arguments>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Remove block from Cart Page:
VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="cart.summary">
            <referenceBlock name="checkout.cart.giftcardaccount" remove="true"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Remove Gift Card link from My Account sidebar**
VendorName/ModuleName/view/frontend/layout/customer_account.xml

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <!-- Gift Card link -->
        <referenceBlock name="customer-account-navigation-gift-card-link" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

follow: https://www.sudhanshubajaj.com/magento-commerce-how-to-remove-gift-card-option-from-cart-checkout-and-my-account/